# How to attain 1 double quote only on Json format string in VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, json, .net, vb.net

I have the Below JSON Result.

```json
"{""head"":{""clientID"":""100088optimumremit"",""reqTime"":""2022-01-20T15:06:58+08:00"",""reqMsgID"":""GcashValidate85"",""clientSecret"":""100088optimumremit""},""body"":{""merchantID"":""100088"",""codeString"":""123456"",""codeType"":""REFERENCE_CODE""}}"
```

What I want is the below Result

```json
"{"head":{"clientID":"100088optimumremit","reqTime":"2022-01-20T15:06:58+08:00","reqMsgID":"GcashValidate85","clientSecret":"100088optimumremit"},"body":{"merchantID":"100088","codeString":"123456","codeType":"REFERENCE_CODE"}}"
```

How do I attain the single quote (") only?

Comment: How did you get that JSON? Can't you adjust the generating of it? Or is it a debugger that just *displays* doubled quotes?

Comment: I use New Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject() for generating  JSON Sir Hans.

Comment: NewtonSoft should generate the JSON correctly. I assume you see this in the debugger? Don't just hover over the variable, but use the "View" button to view the real value (the debugger displays it as a sourcecode-ready value, with escaped quotes and such - so there really *isn't* a doubled quote)

Comment: Thank Sir Hans, I'm so stupid..I wasted 2 weeks over this concern..

Answer (score 1):

```
var json = @"{""head"":{""clientID"":""100088optimumremit"",""reqTime"":""2022-01-20T15:06:58+08:00"",""reqMsgID"":""GcashValidate85"",""clientSecret"":""100088optimumremit""},""body"":{""merchantID"":""100088"",""codeString"":""123456"",""codeType"":""REFERENCE_CODE""}}";
var cleanJson = json.Replace("\"\"", "\"");
Console.WriteLine(cleanJson);
```

Comment: Thanks Mashed Spud. 

I tried your Approach I just converted it into "VB" code format and here's the version on the VB

Replace(SignContent.ToString, """""", """")

I get same format on the result.

"{""head"":{""clientID"":""100088optimumremit"",""reqTime"":"" '2021-12-23T13:49:56+08:00' "",""reqMsgID"":"" 'GcashValidate38' "",""clientSecret"":""100088optimumremit""},""body"":{""merchantID"":""100088"",""codeString"":"" '16413024' "",""codeType"":""REFERENCE_CODE""}}"

Multiple Double Quotes Still exist..:(

Answer (score 0):

Generally, You can do regular expression to replace all double quote with single double quote.

You can use `json.Replace("\"\"", "\"")`

Comment: I tried.. but no luck. on VB.